# Error installing xdebug in Centos (Yum install install php-devel)

Tags: php, xdebug, php-7.2

Trying to install xdebug for VS code by following [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) and run into the following error.

Error installing php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4....
Found php-cli 7.2.....

That is when the following is used:

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools" && yum install php-devel autoconf automake
```

Comment: Which repository are you using ? How have you installed PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 install php-devel autoconf automake
```

Comment: If you use "remi-php72", you don't need php-devel, as php-pecl-xdebug is there ;)

Comment: :) thanks for catching that. This is your bread and butter :)